# Where to find programming projects that help science?

Tags: open-source, scientific-computing

I would like to work on a programming project in my spare time and would like to know
if there is a project where I can help the science community in some way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, plenty! I see I'm not the first to think of numerical computation libraries like [Numpy/Scipy](http://www.scipy.org) - the code in that is actually fairly mature but they could certainly use help documenting. There's also [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), which does much of the same things as Numpy but doesn't require Python. A slightly related area in which there's a lot of work to do is computer algebra systems (CAS), basically open source equivalents of Mathematica; for example [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), and more are listed at http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/wdj/sigsam/opensource_math.html. You could also help with visualization libraries, i.e. creation of 2D and 3D plots and figures. For Scipy the most commonly used plot generator is [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), for example. There are also loads of more specialized data visualization tools that I'm sure you can find with a few searches.

One area that I personally think needs a lot of work is creating GUIs for the programs mentioned in the previous paragraph; one major advantage that commercial programs like Matlab and Mathematica enjoy over their open source equivalents is easy-to-use graphical interfaces. Having a nice usable interface would be great for scientists who may not be skilled in command-line-fu, but open source projects have a *long* way to go if they're going to catch up.

Answer (score 6):

Projects like [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) and [numpy](http://www.scipy.org/more_about_SciPy) are largely contributed by the scientific community.  I'm sure they would appreciate any help you thought you could provide.

Answer (score 6):

I know [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) is always looking for help

Edit:  Here is their programming help page http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/DevProjects

Answer (score 5):

The Bio* projects like [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/), [BioPython](http://www.biopython.org/), or [BioRuby](http://www.bioruby.org/) would certainly like some help, too.

Answer (score 3):

http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=science

Answer (score 3):

In addition to searching open source projects online, you can try to contact your local university and ask if any of their researchers (students or faculty) need development help.

If you are still looking, feel free to contact me via my profile page - I know of a hardware product that needs software - it is used for research (chemistry and biology)

Answer (score 2):

The nuclear ad particle physics communities make heavy use of [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/), which is developed using an open source methodology. They accept suggestions and patches without much trouble. The main work is in C++, but there are binding and support for other languages as well.

I'm sure that other disciplines have their own domain specific tools. For instance, I know that there are open Computational Fluid Dynamics and Finite Element systems.

Have a look around. While domain knowledge would be helpful, most big tools are going to need help with routine stuff like RDBMS access, GUIs, documentation, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can discover the current problems of Science by reading the abstracts of the academic journals. e.g. the [Bioinformatics](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/) journal.

A few examples:

- Find a faster/efficient methods to assemble a huge set of [short DNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequence_alignment_software#Short-Read_Sequence_Alignment) reads:
- Find a way to build an efficient [social scientific network](http://blog.openwetware.org/scienceintheopen/2009/02/15/contributor-ids-an-attempt-to-aggregate-and-integrate/)
- Find a way to compare [thousand of human genomes](http://www.1000genomes.org)
- ....

you could also propose your help on [Nature Network:Collaboration](http://network.nature.com/groups/nncollaborations/forum/topics) or [FriendFeed: The life scientists](http://friendfeed.com/rooms/the-life-scientists)

Answer (score 0):

There are many exicting opportunities in chemistry. There is a strong Open Source community, much of which is organized under the Blue Obelisk (http://www.blueobelisk.org). There have been major contributions in visualisation and algorithms which did not need previous chemical knowledge and the community is very welcoming to anyone who wishes to help.

For an example of the standard which has been achieved take a look at Jmol which visualizes molecules and other chemistry in 3D (http://www.jmol.org);

There is also real opportunity to do porting between platforms/languages. The commonest ones are Java, Python, C++ and we have been working in C#. You don't have to be an ace programmer either - contributions to data standards, data resources, tutorials, packaging, installers, testing, etc. are all highly valued.

Some of these projects are within the top 100-500 projects on Sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you find a project to be a bit over your head or you aren't able to really contribute, but you still like the idea of it, you can always donate!